# Align two sections in ms word office?

Tags: ms-word

How do I align the Expertise section with the bullet list in ms word?

[image]

Comment: This is not a programming question. As such, it is off-topic here. General questions about Word usage should be asked in an appropriate end-usrr forum (e.g. MS Answers).

Comment: Hi, adding to macropod's comment, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums.